# Why does an oscillator want a capacitor between Output and Tri-State?

Tags: oscillator, tri-state

I'm looking at the datasheet for an oscillator: ECS-3225MVQ-500-CN-TR

https://www.mouser.se/datasheet/2/122/ECS_3225MVQ-1825332.pdf
[image]

As you can see, if Tri-State is not connected(NC) or pulled high (70% of Vdd voltage), then the Output is active. If Tri-State is pulled low to the ground or 30% of Vdd voltage, then the Output is not active.

But then the datasheet recommends a capacitor between Tri-state and Output. Why?

Comment: You will not be the first to confuse top and bottom views ... nor the last. +1 for asking, hopefully before laying out the PCB!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help you understand things at all: -

[image]

Comment: I see. A couping between Vdd and GND.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson correct.